# Initial&Boundary Value problem-Fourier

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$$u_{t}=u_{xx}, \hspace{5mm} x>0, t>0$$  $$u(0,t)=0 \hspace{3mm} u(x,0)=f(x)$$

We want that the solutions are bounded.

We are looking for solutions of the form $$u(x,t)=X(x) \cdot T(t)$$ 
$X(0)=0$

$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\lambda$

$ \Rightarrow T'(t)+\lambda T(t)=0$

$X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0 \hspace{3mm} X(0)=0$

$\lambda =0 \Rightarrow X(x)=c_1 x+c_2 \\ X(0)=0 \Rightarrow c_2=0 \Rightarrow X(x)=c_1 x \text{  unbounded }  \Rightarrow c_1=0$

$\lambda<0 \Rightarrow X(x)=c_1 e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$

$X(0)=0 \Rightarrow c_1+c_2=0 \Rightarrow c_2=-c_1 \\ X(x)=c_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}-e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}) \text{ unbounded unless } c_1=0$

$ \Rightarrow \lambda >0, X(x)=c_1 \cos (\sqrt{\lambda }x)+c_2 \sin (\sqrt{\lambda}x) \\ \Rightarrow X(0)=0 \Rightarrow c_1=0$

$\lambda >0, \\ u_{\lambda}(x,t)=c_{\lambda}e^{-\lambda t}\sin (\sqrt{\lambda}x) \\ u(x,t)=\int_0^{+\infty} c(\lambda) e^{-\lambda t}\sin (\sqrt{\lambda} x)d \lambda$

$u(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_ke^{-k^2t}\sin (kx)$

For $"t=0"$, $u(x,0)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k\sin (kx)$

$\sin (mx) f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k \sin (kx) \sin (mx), m \in \mathbb{N}$

$f \sim \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k \sin (kx)$

$ \Rightarrow \int_0^{\pi}f(x) \sin (mx)dx=\int_0^{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k\sin (kx) \sin (mx) dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k \int_0^{\pi}\sin (kx) \sin (mx)dx=c_m \frac{\pi}{2}$

$\Rightarrow c_m=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}f(x)(\sin (mx)dx , m=1,2, \dots $

$u(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k e^{-k^2t}\sin (kx)$

$$$$

I have the following questions:

Why do we take at the part:

$\lambda >0, \\ u_{\lambda}(x,t)=c_{\lambda}e^{-\lambda t}\sin (\sqrt{\lambda}x) \\ u(x,t)=\int_0^{+\infty} c(\lambda) e^{-\lambda t}\sin (\sqrt{\lambda} x)d \lambda$

$u(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_ke^{-k^2t}\sin (kx)$

first the integral and then the sum ??

$$$$

We have that $x \in (0, +\infty)$. At the part:

$\int_0^{\pi}f(x) \sin (mx)dx=\int_0^{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k\sin (kx) \sin (mx) dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k \int_0^{\pi}\sin (kx) \sin (mx)dx=c_m \frac{\pi}{2}$

why do we take the integral over the interval $(0, \pi)$ ??

Comment: The solution can be written in terms of the Fourier (sine) Transform, not a series since the domain of definition is unbounded (in both $x>0$ and $t>0$).

Comment: But why do we write it, after having written the integral, as a sum ?? @Dr.MV

Comment: Is $f$ periodic with period $\pi$? If not, can one write a viable solution as a Fourier series with basis function that have period $\pi$?

Comment: It isn't given that $f$ is periodic. What is a viable solution ?? @Dr.MV

Comment: The viable solution is the one written in terms of the Fourier sine Transform.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. Here is the correct approach:

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $X(x)T'(t)-X''(x)T(t)=0$

$X(x)T'(t)=X''(x)T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-s^2$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-s^2\\X''(x)+s^2X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{-ts^2}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)\sin xs+c_2(s)\cos xs&\text{when}~s\neq0\\c_1x+c_2&\text{when}~s=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-ts^2}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-ts^2}\cos xs~ds$

$u(0,t)=0$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-ts^2}~ds=0$

$C_2(s)=0$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-ts^2}\sin xs~ds$

$u(x,0)=f(x)$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)\sin xs~ds=f(x)$

$\mathcal{F}_{s,s\to x}\{C_1(s)\}=f(x)$

$C_1(s)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\{f(x)\}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\{f(x)\}e^{-ts^2}\sin xs~ds$